# Efficiently querying a GROUP BY with a predicate on the max in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given the following data, I want to answer the question:

> from *only the most recent states* of entities with `id`,
>   select the `(id, time)` where `x = 9`

```
id | time | x
-------------
1  | 1    | 9 
1  | 3    | 7
2  | 3    | 7
2  | 4    | 9
...
```

We should return just:

```
id | time 
---------
2  | 4
...
```

The following query answers the question:

```sql
SELECT id, time
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, time
    FROM t
    ORDER BY id, time DESC NULLS LAST
) AS most_recent
ON t.id = most_recent.id AND t.time = most_recent.time
WHERE x = 9
```

But even with these indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_rank ON t (id, time DESC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX idx_x ON t (x);
```

The query is slow with lots of data as it has to join *all* the most recent `(id, time)`s

```
 Merge Join
   Merge Cond: t.id = most_recent.id AND t.time = most_recent.time
   ->  Unique  
         ->  Index Only Scan using idx_rank
   ->  Sort
         Sort Key: t.id, t.time DESC NULLS LAST
         ->  Index Scan using idx_x on t
               Index Cond: x = 9
```

Putting the predicate in twice speeds up the query:

```sql
SELECT id, time
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, time
    FROM t
    JOIN (
        SELECT t.id
        FROM t
        WHERE x = 9
    ) AS inner_filter
    ON t.id = inner_filter.id
    ORDER BY t.id, t.time DESC NULLS LAST
) AS most_recent
ON t.id = most_recent.id AND t.time = most_recent.time
WHERE x = 9
```

But feels a really ugly, especially with more complicated predicates involving joins etc, is there any other way?